# Unity doesn't resolve my classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container, unit-of-work

I have more projects in solution (mostly class library and one WebAPI project) and I have problem in Common project in resolving dependencies inside this project. Here is example how I setting up dependency

```
    [Dependency]
    public IDbContextFactory DbContextFactory
    {
        get { return _factory; }
        set
        {
            _factory = value;
            DbContext = _factory.Create();
        }
    }
    [Dependency]
    public IUnitOfWorkManager Manager
    {
        get { return _manager; }
        set
        {
            _manager = value;
            _manager.AddOpenUnitOfWork(this);
        }
    }
```

and in same project I have registration interfaces and classes into Unity container via this class

```
public class CommonUnityConfiguration : IUnityConfiguration
{
    public void Configurate(UnityContainer container)
    {
        container
            .RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkManager, UnitOfWorkManager>()
            .RegisterType<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory>();
    }
}
```

and finally in WebAPI I have WebApiConfiguration, where I'm creating Unity container and register all classes.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Create instance for Unity container - let's try to run!
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        // Add project classes to IoC container
        new CommonUnityConfiguration().Configurate(container);

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Problem is, IDbContextFactory property and IUnitOfWorkManager aren't resolve. Do you have any advice, what should I check?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch these two lines:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);

new CommonUnityConfiguration().Configurate(container);
```

You're setting the DependencyResolver to the UnityREsolver before you fully configure it in your CommonUnityConfiguration class

Comment: Thanks for comment, but problem was between monitor and char - me. I was trying to create new instance of UnitOfWork by calling "new UnitOfWork()" and I excepted, that dependencies will be fill. But then I realized, that Unity not tracking of creating new instances and I can not work like this...